# C# format DateTime without year

Tags: c#, datetime, internationalization, date-formatting

Is there a possibility to format a DateTime without a year and with the month in a numerical representation that's internationalized?

e.g. new DateTime(2018, 8, 10) (today)

On the one hand we have "d" for `10.08.2018` (German) or `2018/08/10` (Japanese).

On the other hand we have "M" that gives us `10. August` (German) or `August 10` (US English)

But what I want is `10.08.` (German), `08/10` (Japanese), `8/10` (US English), `10/08` (British English)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: @mjwills thanks, but as far as I can see,those are not internationalizable (is that a word?) I have to give the order and delimiters myself.

Comment: Thanks, me neither, that's why I asked.

Comment: See also [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeformatinfo.cs) -- there is no property like "DayBeforeMonth" you could leverage.  All patterns that are specific like that are set individually. -- What you *could* do is get the `ShortDatePattern` for example and test if `d` is before `M` yourself and then have a custom format ready. Note that `"/"` should automatically be replaced by the culture specific `DateSeparator`.

Comment: Nowhere (afaik) is stored if the day-month pattern should end with the delimiter like you expect it to be for german dates(`10.08.`).

Comment: So it looks like I either need to build some complex logic for it or need to tell the Designers that they need to plan in more space for "M" or "d".

Comment: I can't see in any list of date formats that the delimiter is needed if it's not a dot, so the logic (maybe not that complex) would be similar to Coraks comment. Replace yyyy and surrounding delimiters, if the delimiter is . add it again at the end.

Comment: Short date without year is probably not available by design as Thomas G. says: [there is probably no defined convention for displaying only the month and day portions of a date both as numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19186265/433718)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could take the `ShortDatePattern` from `DateTimeFormatInfo` and strip out the yyyy?

You would have to get a little creative to remove the separator with it.

A Replace chain

```
.Replace(DateFormatInfo.DateSeparator+"yyyy")
.Replace("yyyy"+DateFormatInfo.DateSeparator)
```

A Regex might do the trick `^y+[^0-9A-Za-z]+|[^0-9A-Za-z]+y+$`

```
  string[]  cultures = { "en-US", "ja-JP", "fr-FR" };
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2011, 5, 1);

  Console.WriteLine(" {0,7} {1,19} {2,10}\n", "CULTURE", "PROPERTY VALUE", "DATE");

  foreach (var culture in cultures) {
     DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture).DateTimeFormat;
     Console.WriteLine(" {0,7} {1,19} {2,10}", culture, 
                       dtfi.ShortDatePattern, 
                       date1.ToString("d", dtfi));
  }

CULTURE      PROPERTY VALUE       
en-US            M/d/yyyy  
ja-JP          yyyy/MM/dd 
fr-FR          dd/MM/yyyy
```

From :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.shortdatepattern?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: How to strip out the year? Because you had to know if the date-delimiter would come before or after the year

Comment: Hmm... `dtfi.ShortDatePattern.Replace("yyyy", "").Trim("/")` and add a `"/"` again at the end if `DateSeparator` is `"."`? -- fragile and potentially error prone, but might be "good enough" for standard use cases...

Comment: added a possible Regex, you'll have to test of course

Comment: `DateFormatInfo.DateSeparator ` could be used to do a replace `.Replace(DateFormatInfo.DateSeparator+"yyyy").Replace("yyyy"+DateFormatInfo.DateSeparator)`

Comment: I just tried it, @Corak s solution doesn't work for DateSeparator "-" or " ", but that should be fixed with "(yyyy[ /.\-])|([ /.\-]yyyy)" Regex

Comment: @RichardHubley - Keep in mind that for example in culture `"de-DE"` the result should be `"10.08."`.

Comment: @Corak interesting, I assumed that was a copy-paste error. DateTime seems to be one of the hardest things in programming

Comment: ... and Serbian (`"sr"`), Bosnian (`"bs"`) or Croatian ("`hr`") with a `ShortDatePattern` like `"d.M.yyyy."` (dot after year) also need special handling -- and probably a handfull of other special formats. -- @RichardHubley - Indeed... just reading Jon Skeets musings about Noda Time gives me chills...

Comment: `var formats = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).GroupBy(c => c.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern); foreach (var format in formats.OrderByDescending(f => f.Count())) { Console.WriteLine($"{format.Key} - ({format.Count()} cultures)"); }`